# svg image is not displaying

Tags: reactjs, vite

```
import React from "react";
import ReactLogo from "./image/react.svg";
import TypeScript from "./image/typescript.svg";
import MongoDB from "./image/logo_mongodb_icon.svg";
import JavaScript from "./image/logo-javascript.svg";
import NodeJS from "./image/logo_nodejs_icon.svg";
import Express from "./image/expressjs-icon.svg";
import Python from "./image/python-4.svg";

function Main() {
  const images = [
    { src: "ReactLogo", alt: "react" },
    { src: "Typescript", alt: "typescript" },
    { src: "MongoDB", alt: "mngodb" },
    { src: "Javascript", alt: "javascript" },
    { src: "NodeJS", alt: "nodejs" },
    { src: "Express", alt: "express" },
    { src: "Python", alt: "python" },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {images.map((image, index) => (
          <img key={index} src={image.src} alt={image.alt} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

i am trying to add svg icons of various programming languages to my site but they are NOT displaying and just showing the alt text. the svgs were downloaded online and are imported correctly

i tried uploading svgs but they are not displaying. this is a jsx file

Comment: Your `src` properties in `images` are strings, not the imported images.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a string as `src` instead of the actual import. Use the imports as the `src`.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactLogo from "./image/react.svg";
import TypeScript from "./image/typescript.svg";
import MongoDB from "./image/logo_mongodb_icon.svg";
import JavaScript from "./image/logo-javascript.svg";
import NodeJS from "./image/logo_nodejs_icon.svg";
import Express from "./image/expressjs-icon.svg";
import Python from "./image/python-4.svg";

function Main() {
  const images = [
    { src: ReactLogo, alt: "react" },
    { src: Typescript, alt: "typescript" },
    { src: MongoDB, alt: "mngodb" },
    { src: Javascript, alt: "javascript" },
    { src: NodeJS, alt: "nodejs" },
    { src: Express, alt: "express" },
    { src: Python, alt: "python" },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {images.map((image, index) => (
          <img key={index} src={image.src} alt={image.alt} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```